# Who owes who money optimization 

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, graph

Say you have n people, each who owe each other money. In general it should be possible to reduce the amount of transactions that need to take place. i.e. if X owes Y £4 and Y owes X £8, then Y only needs to pay X £4 (1 transaction instead of 2).

This becomes harder when X owes Y, but Y owes Z who owes X as well. I can see that you can easily calculate one particular cycle. It helps for me when I think of it as a fully connected graph, with the edges being the amount each person owes.

Problem seems to be NP-complete, but what kind of optimisation algorithm could I make, nevertheless, to reduce the **total** amount of transactions? Doesn't have to be that efficient, as N is quite small for me.

Edit:

The purpose of this problem would be to be able to have in the accounting system something that can say to each person when they log in "You can remove M amount of transactions by simply paying someone X amount, and someone else Y amount". Hence the bank solution (though optimal if everyone is paying at the same time) cannot really be used here.

Comment: It appears Expensure have solved this problem. See their faq entry [Circular Debt Resolution™](http://expensure.com/home/faq).

Comment: If there are no transaction costs, there is a simple solution involving a bank. If there are transaction costs, it is way more difficult.

Comment: We can modify the problem to eliminate the bank issue. Let's add the constraint, "a person can be involved in at most (N-1) transactions". So no bank, no nominee.

Comment: By the way, what is the core purpose of this optimization? Is it making the process faster or something that isn't included in the question?

Comment: One more question: is default possible ?

Comment: I looked at doing something advanced like this but then concluded that debt transferring is in practice a bad idea if you don't 100% trust everybody to pay their debts. If some debts might be bad you don't want them transferred to you to cover some otherwise good debts. In effect debts have a value different from their monetary label. This might be a case that can be ignored here but it is an interesting real world consideration.

Answer (score 8):

Are people required to clear their debts by paying somebody that they actually owe money to personally? If not, the following seems to work suspiciously easily:

For each person, work out the net amount they should pay, or should receive.

Have somebody who owes money net pay somebody who should receive money net min(amount owed, amount to be received). After this, at least one of the two participants owes nothing and should receive nothing, and so can be removed from the problem.

Assuming I have missed something, what are the constraints that apply (or gross error made)?

Comment: I think you need to follow the money path - otherwise - you can have 2 circles that has no connection between them and you push money from one to another.

Comment: Based on the description, your solution can be accepted as correct :)

Comment: It is a socialistic idea :-) to put all the owed money in a pot and divide it between the people that should get it.

Comment: "Are people required to clear their debts by paying somebody that they actually owe money to personally?" A no-arbitrage argument shows that you can always relax this by using a bank, as you did. This means that you tacitely suppose the transactions take place at no cost. If there are transaction costs (eg. debts are labelled in multiple currencies, or simply money transfer costs something), the problem is really more subtle.

Comment: I have used this to figure out shared trip costs among multiple people. I've been puzzled how some people can make simple thing so complex.

Comment: That's definitely a good solution presuming everyone wants to pay at the same time. But supposing they don't? (as in my case). Rather everyone owes everyone money, and it would be nice to have a suggestion like "You can complete these 5 transactions by just paying X some £W amount".

Comment: Sort creditors by amount owed. Each time someone is willing to pay, pay as much creditors you can and sort the list again.

Comment: @Francis: Things get more complicated since interest rates are to be taken into account.

Comment: @Nicolas: The usual convention is to pay the most senior debt first.

Comment: This algorithm removes at least one person per transaction. The only way I can think of reducing transactions from there is to check first for pairs of people where one owes exactly what another is due and then match them up first.

Comment: This is an excellent starting point for the optimal solution. From here, you basically have a kind of optimal packing problem where you have net debtors paying net creditors so that you minimize transactions.

Answer (score 4):

I have created an Android app which solves this problem. You can input expenses during the trip, it even recommends you "who should pay next". At the end it calculates "who should send how much to whom". My algorithm calculates minimum required number of transactions and you can setup "transaction tolerance" which can reduce transactions even further (you don't care about $1 transactions) Try it out, it's called Settle Up:

https://market.android.com/details?id=cz.destil.settleup

**Description of my algorithm:**

I have basic algorithm which solves the problem with n-1 transactions, but it's not optimal. It works like this: From payments, I compute balance for each member. Balance is what he paid minus what he should pay. I sort members according to balance increasingly. Then I always take the poorest and richest and transaction is made. At least one of them ends up with zero balance and is excluded from further calculations. With this, number of transactions cannot be worse than n-1. It also minimizes amount of money in transactions. But it's not optimal, because it doesn't detect subgroups which can settle up internally.

Finding subgroups which can settle up internally is hard. I solve it by generating all combinations of members and checking if sum of balances in subgroup equals zero. I start with 2-pairs, then 3-pairs ... (n-1)pairs. Implementations of combination generators are available. When I find a subgroup, I calculate transactions in the subgroup using basic algorithm described above. For every found subgroup, one transaction is spared.

The solution is optimal, but complexity increases to O(n!). This looks terrible but the trick is there will be just small number of members in reality. I have tested it on Nexus One (1 Ghz procesor) and the results are: until 10 members: <100 ms, 15 members: 1 s, 18 members: 8 s, 20 members: 55 s. So until 18 members the execution time is fine. Workaround for >15 members can be to use just the basic algorithm (it's fast and correct, but not optimal).

**Source code:**

Source code is available inside a report about algorithm written in Czech. Source code is at the end and it's in English:

http://settleup.destil.cz/report.pdf

Comment: PDF is not available

Answer (score 3):

Nominate one person arbitrarily to be the banker.

Each other person transfers the sum of all the outgoing transactions minus the incoming transactions (so either deposits or withdraws) to that person.

There will be a maximum of (n-1) transactions, which is pretty small. It is fast. It is simple.

Given that everyone who transfers money will have to be involved in a transaction anyway*, it is bounded to be at worst twice the optimal case.**

* The exception is the banker themselves. A quick optimisation is to ensure the nominated banker is not someone who holds a neutral position.

** Explaining my upper bound logic further:

Suppose the optimal case is A gives $1 to B, and C gives $1 to D, and E is neutral = two transactions.

Then with this logic, if E is the nominated banker,  A gives $1 to E, E gives $1 to B, C gives $1 to E and E gives $1 to D = four transactions.

With the optimisation, making sure you don't choose a neutral person for banker, select A instead.
A gives $1 to B, C gives $1 to A. A gives $1 to D = three transactions.

Comment: Actually, it is easier for the "bank" to be external to the participants.

Comment: @Alexandre C., agreed, if that is permitted.

Comment: it is always possible to imagine it is permitted.

Comment: That's how it is done in practice http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Counterparty_Clearing

Answer (score 3):

```
for each debt in debts
  debt.creditor.owed -= debt.amount
  debt.deptor.owed += debt.amount
end

for each person in persons
  if person.owed > 0 then
    deptors.add person
  else if person.owed < 0 then
    creditors.add person
  end
end

deptors.sort_by_owed_desc
creditor.sort_by_owed_asc

for each debtor in deptors
  while debtor.owed > 0
    creditor = creditors.top
    amount = min( debtor.owed, -creditor.owed)
    creditor.owed += amount
    debtor.owed -= amount
    if creditor.owed == 0 then
      creditors.remove_top
    end
    write debtor.name " owes " creditor.name " " amount "€"
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to be the algorithm for mcdowella's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554655/who-owes-who-money-optimization-problem/4554799#4554799 ...

Comment: _A bit of code is worth a thousand words_! You're right though, looks like it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking about it I'd start by looking at each cycle in the directed graph and reducing each edge in the cycle by the value of the minimum edge in the cycle, then remove the minimum edge altogether. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: This is the basic approach, but you might clear one "small" cycle and make another huge cycle unpayable. the problem here is to try and optimize the algorithm, which is not simple, and probably np-complete (to find the actual optimal solution).

Comment: You might do better finding all cycles and greedily taking the cycle with the max min edge, then doing to it what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Python solution I used; it's the same idea as Gunner's post, with a few line changes:

```
for i in N:
    for j in N:
        if i!=j and owes[i][j] > owes[j][i]:
            owes[i][j] -= owes[j][i]
            owes[j][i] = 0
for k in N:
    for i in N:
        for j in N:
            if k == i or i == j or k == j:
                continue
            if owes[j][k] > owes[i][j]:
                owes[i][k] += owes[i][j]
                owes[j][k] -= owes[i][j]
                owes[i][j] = 0;
```

Works a treat.

You can test it with i.e.:

```
owes = [[0,2,11], [4,0,7], [2,3,0]]
N = range(len(owes))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build a different data structure ( a tree, each time one person is the root node) that will check for each person how many "transaction" can you "kill", than, choose the best one, make the cycle, and rebuild it again.it is not o(N), I Think it's N^2 though, and it will not give you the best result. it is just a strategy.

Comment: Just my thoughts how to deal with it. I'm sure there are better ways to get an optimum result.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be tackled with the Warshall algorithm.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    if ( i!= j && owes[i][j] > owes[j][i] )
owes[i][j] -= (owes[i][j] - owes[j][i]), owes[j][i] = 0;

for(k=0;k<n;k++)
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
if( k == i || i == j || k == j ) continue;
if ( owes[j][k] > owes[i][j] )
{
int diff = owes[j][k] - owes[i][j]; 
owes[i][j] = 0;
owes[i][k ] += diff;
owes[j][k] -= diff;
} 
}
```

After the algorithm finishes, the total number of transactions required would be the number of positive entries in the owes table.

I have not verified yet whether the algorithm will work, based on nature of the problem it may work. Solution is O(N^3).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must remove all cicles reducing edges by minimal edge value and removingedges with value 0. After it you will get graph withouth cicles.  I think you must find vertexes, wich have no pointers to them (man's wich owes only others money). This man's must pay money, beacouse there is no one to pay the money for them. So my point is that you must find somehow who they must pay.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to the problem written in matlab. It is based on a matrix of who owes who what. The number in the (i,j) means that person j owes person i the number. E.g.

B owes A 2
and A owes B 1

of course in this case it is trivial that B should just give A 1

This becomes more complex with more entries. However, with the algorithm i wrote i can guarantee that no more than N-1 transactions occurs where N is the number of persones 2 in this case.

Here is the code i wrote.

```
function out = whooweswho(matrix)
%input sanitation
if ~isposintscalar(matrix)
    [N M] = size(matrix);
    if N ~= M
        error('Matrix must be square');
    end

    for i=1:N
        if matrix(N,N) ~= 0
            error('Matrix must have zero on diagonals');
        end
    end
else
    %construction of example matrix if input is a positive scalar
    disp('scalar input: Showing example of NxN matrix randomly filled');
    N = matrix;
    matrix = round(10*N*rand(N,N)).*(ones(N,N)-eye(N))
end

%construction of vector containing each persons balance
net = zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
  net(i) = sum(matrix(i,:))-sum(matrix(:,i));
end

%zero matrix, so it can be used for the result
matrix = zeros(size(matrix));

%sum(net) == 0 always as no money dissappears. So if min(net) == 0 it
%implies that all balances are zero and we are done.
while min(net) ~= 0
  %find the poorest and the richest.
  [rec_amount reciever] = max(net);
  [give_amount giver] = min(net);
  %balance so at least one of them gets zero balance.
  amount =min(abs(rec_amount),abs(give_amount));
  net(reciever) = net(reciever) - amount;
  net(giver) = net(giver) + amount;
  %store result in matrix.
  matrix(reciever,giver) = amount;
end
%output equivalent matrix of input just reduced.
out = matrix;
```

end