# Balancing algorithm to even out differences?

Tags: algorithm

Say, we have `N` number of accounts with positive balances `B_1, ..., B_n`.

We can make a transfer `T(from,to,amount)` which moves certain amount of balance between accounts.

We have knowledge about an optimal distribution of balances `O_1, ..., O_n`.

The question is: How can we find the minimum set of transfers that achieve the optimal distribution? Can we always get away with `N-1` transfers at most?

Example:

```
Balances  {0}: 10, {1}: 40, {2}: 50
Optimal   {0}: 20, {1}: 60, {2}: 20

T(2,0,10) => {0}: 20, {1}: 40, {2}: 40
T(2,1,20) => {0}: 20, {1}: 60, {2}: 20
```

Comment: Yes. Because you will never be forced to make more then `N-1` transfers for `N` accounts. Why? One must be unbalanced to necessitate the balancing operation. You could graph the linear requirements with [Linear Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Comment: Take your pick of dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163116/algorithm-to-determine-minimum-payments-amongst-a-group or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554655/who-owes-who-money-optimization or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723165/algorithm-to-simplify-a-weighted-directed-graph-of-debts

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can always get away with no more than `N-1` transfer. Here is a proof by induction:

1. For `N=2`, it is obvious that no more than a single transfer is required.
2. For `N>2`, there are two cases:

   1. We are already at the optimal distribution, in which case there's nothing to do.
   2. There exist `i` and `j` such that `B_i > O_i` and `B_j < O_j`. Transfer `min(B_i - O_i, O_j - B_j)` from account `i` to account `j`. **This balances one of the two accounts, thereby reducing the problem to the `N-1` case.**

The proof is constructive, giving you an algorithm. The algorithm does not attempt to minimise the number of transfers.

It is easy to come up with heuristics for reducing the number of steps. It is a bit late in the day for me to be thinking hard about optimality, but it would not surprise me if the problem turned out to be NP-hard.

Comment: To me it feels like the problem of reducing the number of transfers is equivalent to finding subsets where the required increases and decreases sum to 0 (because then if you sort out all but one of these accounts, the final account is automatically solved as well).  However, subset sum is NP-complete, so I agree that the optimal solution to this problem seems likely to be NP-hard.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz [Yep, it's NP-hard.](http://www.mathmeth.com/tom/files/settling-debts.pdf)